# In CCCallFuncND we pass pointers. Is it a good practice to pass pointer of local scope

Tags: c++, ios, pointers, cocos2d-x

In CCCallFuncND  we pass pointers . Is it a good practice to pass pointer of local scope(i.e. pointers  declared and allocated in a member) from another method.

The method is like:-

```
CCCallFuncND * CCCallFuncND::create(CCObject* pSelectorTarget, SEL_CallFuncND selector,    void* d)
{
    CCCallFuncND* pRet = new CCCallFuncND();

    if (pRet && pRet->initWithTarget(pSelectorTarget, selector, d))
    {
        pRet->autorelease();
        return pRet;
    }

    CC_SAFE_DELETE(pRet);
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: I want to know is it safe to pass a pointer variable like this?

Comment: You mean you pass pointers to local variables to the function you describe in your question? Or do you ask if it's safe to pass on the pointer arguments to the function you call?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg i want to pass a pointer variable. This function is inbuilt in cocos2d-x. Do i need special care about passed pointer(i.e. it shouldn't be deleted as long as this method and threads called on this pointer survives)

Comment: If you're asking about passing on the `pSelectorTarget` or `d` pointers to the `initWithTarget`function, then that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a good practice. You can pass, but you can't use it if you didn't run the CCCallFuncND immediately. if you put it in to a CCSequence and run it later, the void* will pointing to some invalid address.

Answer (score 0):

It's safe as long as you don't return pointers to local variables (which will go out of scope once you return from method). With new memory for object is allocated on heap (be careful with placement new) and hence it is safe to return it from a function.
Factory Pattern does the same thing.
http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html

Comment: Also care has to be take that the function you pass the pointer to doesn't store it for later use, if the pointer is a pointer to a local variable.